# Can't upload using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, upload, phantomjs

I have a php file on my server to upload file. I tried to upload using that file directly and it was success.

Then I wrote a simple phantomjs script, run it on ubuntu with phantomjs version 2.1.1 but it is not success. There was no error displayed but file was not upload.

Below are php file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES["files"]))
{
    $files = $_FILES["files"];
    if($files["name"] != '')
    {

            $fullpath = "./".$files["name"];
            if(move_uploaded_file($files['tmp_name'],$fullpath))
            {                      
                    echo "<h1><a href='$fullpath'>OK-Click here!</a></h1>";        
            }
    }
    echo '<html><head><title>Upload files...</title></head><body><form method=POST enctype="multipart/form-data" action=""><input type="file" name="files"><input type="submit" value="Upload"></form></body></html>';
return;
}
?>
```

And simple phantomjs script to upload file

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
var testindex = 0, loadInProgress = false;


page.onLoadStarted = function() {
  loadInProgress = true;
  console.log("load started");
};

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
  loadInProgress = false;
  console.log("load finished");
};

function load()
{
    page.open("http://myserver.com/upload.php?cmd=upload")  
}

function upload()
{
    page.uploadFile('input[name=files]', '/home/user/Desktop/log_no_debug.png');    
    page.render("result.png")
}



var steps = [
    load,
    upload
]

interval = setInterval(function() {
  if (!loadInProgress && typeof steps[testindex] == "function") {
    //console.log("step " + (testindex + 1));
    steps[testindex]();
    testindex++;
  }
  if (typeof steps[testindex] != "function") {
    //console.log("test complete!");
    phantom.exit();
  }
}, 50);
```

Below are result.png rendered from the upload.js script

[image: result render]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason file is not uploaded is because you only choose it on the client side, but do not send to the server - you don't submit the form in your PhantomJS script.

I've modified your script a bit, look for comments:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
var testindex = 0, loadInProgress = false;

page.onLoadStarted = function() {
  loadInProgress = true;
  console.log("load started");
};

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
  loadInProgress = false;
  console.log("load finished");
};

function load()
{
    page.open("http://test/upload.php?cmd=upload")  
}

function upload()
{
    loadInProgress = true;
    page.uploadFile('input[name=files]', '/path/to/file.ext');    

    // Here we submit the form to the server
    page.evaluate(function(){
        // document.querySelectorAll("input[type=submit]")[0].click();
        document.querySelectorAll("form")[0].submit();
    });
}

// And only after the page has reloaded it is time to make a screenshot
function finish()
{
    page.render("result.png");
}

var steps = [
    load,
    upload,
    finish
]

interval = setInterval(function() {
  if (!loadInProgress && typeof steps[testindex] == "function") {
    //console.log("step " + (testindex + 1));
    steps[testindex]();
    testindex++;
  }
  if (typeof steps[testindex] != "function") {
    //console.log("test complete!");
    phantom.exit();
  }
}, 500);
```

Comment: Oh, this worked. I worked as tutorials on the internet but never know we need to submit form. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

First of all think carefully where and why you are using @ before variable name.

```
 $files = @$_FILES["files"];
```

A little fragment from: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

> **Warning**
>   Currently the **"@"** error-control operator prefix will even disable error reporting for critical errors that will terminate script execution. Among other things, this means that if you use "@" to suppress errors from a certain function and either it isn't available or has been mistyped, the script will die right there with no indication as to why.

Please dump your **$_FILES["files"]** and check if files/s data are there, if the answer is yes, then dump your **$fullpath**, and be sure that it`s correct.

Can you try to fix this line:

```
<form method=POST enctype="multipart/form-data" action=""><input type=submit value="Upload">
```

to

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=""><input type="submit" value="Upload">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the problem is that I can upload the file by browsing that php file directly. But it is not successfully when I use phantomjs

Comment: Ohh i see,nevertheless are you sure that $_Files["files"] is getting right files? I mean rest of the code seams ok.

Comment: Yes, it is getting the right file as I tried to upload many times and it always ok.